# Оптимальный подход к задаче

Tags: python-3.x, django

У меня есть список со словарями, в котором хранится имя и юрл элементов, которые потом отображаются в шаблоне.

```
menu = [
    {'title': 'О сайте', 'url_name': 'about'},
    {'title': 'Добавить статью', 'url_name': 'add_page'},
    {'title': 'Обратная связь', 'url_name': 'contact'},
    {'title': "Войти", 'url_name': 'login'},
]
```

Я хочу чтобы "добавить статью" видели только авторизованные пользователи и придумал такое решение:

```
  user_menu = menu.copy()
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_menu.pop(1)
    context['menu'] = user_menu
```

Как по мне это какой то костыль, да ещё и затратно по памяти (бессмысленные копии). Хотел в шаблоне как то с помощью проверок, но что то недокумекал как, поэтому пришёл сюда

Comment: действительно, зачем здесь копия, если можно работать напрямую, но если уж очень хочется то del в помощь

Comment: @ganz, :D а как мне поможет del?) Если я удалю раз, оно удалится вообще, т.к. список изменяемый. А напрямую - по конкретней)

Comment: context['menu'].pop(1), как я понимаю. (del для удаления копии списка)

Comment: @ganz , так а разницы не имеет. Итог один и тот же.  Я к тому что, как в шаблоне сделать что то вроде этого:
for m in menu:
if not request.user.is_auth and m['title'] == 'Добавить статью':
 continue
*отображение *

Comment: тогда как-то так if {'title': "Войти", 'url_name': 'login'} not in menu: menu.remove(menu.index({'title': 'Добавить статью', 'url_name': 'add_page'})), естественно если авторизованые не видят кнопки войти. Но по хорошему нужно смотреть на формирование переменной menu

Comment: @ganz , а джанго можно как то перейти сразу к следующей итерации? (как с continue)

Comment: хз, дальше flask'a не продвинулся